# ping to windows ce 5 device with usb connected

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

When I connect my Win7 PC to a windows ce 5 device by Windows Mobile Center, the windows ce device is assigned an ip address `192.168.55.101`.

Is it a way to reach that address using a `ping`? Does this make sense?

Running an `ipconfig` on my PC gives the result

> ipv4 address: 144.93.29.30
>
> subnet mask: 255.255.254.0
>
> default gateway: 144.93.28.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Ping uses ICMP and the "network" connection created by WMDC does not forward ICMP packets.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find a link where to get more information about that. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: More information about what?  ICMP packets are simply not forwarded.  You can't adjust that behavior.